# Ошибка при использовании modsecurity на apache2 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, безопасность

Я установила mod security  https://shortbread.me/install-modsecurity-2-9-on-ubuntu-14-04. В конце выдает следующую ошибку:

```
    # service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                       [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 97 of /etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf:
ModSecurity: Found another rule with the same id
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Comment: а установленный пакет вы удалили? (`libapache2-modsecurity`, `libapache2-mod-security2` и т.п., точное имя можно увидеть, например, командой `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep security`).

Comment: Нужно удалить? $ rm libapache2-mod-security2

Comment: да, нужно удалить пакет: `$ sudo apt-get remove имя-пакета`,

Comment: @alexander barakin а Вы можете объяснить почему нужно  удалить пакет?

Comment: потому что, возможно, в конфигурационных файлах продублированы какие-то идентификаторы, о чём написано в вашем вопросе. вполне возможно, что достаточно и отключить модуль стандартными средствами.

Comment: A можете сказать, как можно проверить, что после удаление пакета, у меня работает modsecurity?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33576/discussion-between-narine-grigoryan-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: ну, вы же ставите модуль более новой версии, чем есть в репозитории, с какой-то целью? вероятно, что-то у вас без него не работало или работало неправильно. а теперь должно заработать.

Comment: Да после удаления пакет у меня локалхост работает нормально, а вот незнаю как проверить, что modecurity активна

Comment: т.е., вы ставили более новую версию лишь для развлечения? извините, тут я вам не помощник.

Comment: Это не для развлечения, в любом случае спасибо за помощь.